# SQL php vars syntax error

Tags: mysql

I need help with following part of login php script:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["login"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["password"]);

$sql = "SELECT FROM usersdata WHERE user_password = $password AND user_name = $name";
```

The server is giving me following error:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM usersdata WHERE user_password = something AND user_name =
>   something' at line 1".

Obviously there is a error with writing php variables in query string such as they are, but I dont know exactly how i should contecate them. Its ridiciolous how SQL queries can be sometimes so frustrating when everything else is working perfectly.

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, instead ***`bind`*** your parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `columns` or `*` in the query. It should be :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usersdata WHERE user_password = $password AND user_name = $name";
```

Also use prepared statements.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Right, seen it just after I posted a question and I couldn't see it whole day yesterday:). Thank you.